# How to read a list of all users and their permissions of a certain team drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, user-permissions, google-drive-shared-drive

I would like to create in spreadsheet a list of all users how have access to a certain team drive (by name) including their permission.

And would like to change, revoke or limit by date the permission.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

### In Apps Script you need to [enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) which allows you to use methods of the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive)

- In specific, you need the method `Drive.Permissions.list(fileId, optionalArgs)`
- For this method, you need to specify the ID, no the name of the drive
- If you don't know the ID, you can `Logger.log` the results of `Drive.Teamdrives.list()` which lists all your drive including name and ID
- For optional properties you need to specify `"supportsTeamDrives" : true`
- For changing the permission, you need the method `Drive.Permissions.update(resource, fileId, permissionId, optionalArgs)`, specifying the parameters as indicated [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update)